# initial migrations file into virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am trying to setup a virtual envirorment on my windows 10 laptop in cmd for a homework assignment and I'm having problems with the instructions given. I was able to get the enviroment up and running and download the requirements, but now the instructions say to `Run the initial migrations with: ./manage.py migrate` When I try to run the code given, I get an error saying that `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` From the research I did the instructions that they give are for a different command language (from what I found it said Linux, but I'm preaty sure thats an operating system). I have tried looking up initial migrations with virtualenv, but I couldn't find information related to my situation. I'll post the full instructions below. Does anyone know how I can proceed?

1. In the root directory, where `manage.py` resides, do the following (all commands run from this dir)
2. Set up a virtual environment with virtualenv venv (virtualenv installation guide - note you may need to use sudo with the installation like sudo pip install virtualenv)
3. Activate virtualenv by with `. venv/bin/activate`
4. Install pip requirements by with `pip install -r requirements.txt`
5. Run the initial migrations with `./manage.py migrate`
6. Create you own user so you can login to the admin panel with `./manage.py createsuperuser`
7. Run the local web server with `./manage.py runserver`
8. Check to see if it works by visiting: http://localhost:8000/admin/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put python instead of ./
So try :

### `python manage.py migrate`

OR

### `python3 manage.py migrate`

OR

### `python3.6 manage.py migrate`

The number after python is the version of python with which you installed venv.

Answer (score 0):

here is my take on this question;
first make sure that the virtual env is running and you are working in a virtual enviroment then make sure all that both python and django are succesfully installed before going any further. in your root directory where jango lives, type in:

```
    django-admin help
```

if you see some commands coming up then it means the django is properly installed if not then try using an editor. i prefer VS Code as it is easy to manage and user friendly and less demanding compared to others and it has an integrated terminal aswell this will solve your problem.